# binary tree symmetry - prints wrong answer

Tags: python, python-3.x

hi i'm trying to learn python for university but seem to can't get out of it.. i wrote this, i know there are errors but i really don't understand. if someone could help me, thanks a lot! (i'm already happy it at least prints something) -- I'm sorry! the exercise, from leetcode, states the following: *Given the root of a binary tree, check whether it is a mirror of itself (i.e., symmetric around its center).*

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, root = None, lc = None, rc = None):
        self.root = root
        self.lc = lc
        self.rc = rc

        if root is not None: 
            if lc is not None:
                self.lc = Tree()
            if rc is not None:
                self.rc = Tree()

    def isempty(self):
        return self.root is None

    def lsym(t):
        return (t.root, t.lc.lsym(), t.rc)

    def rsym(t):
        return (t.root, t.rc.rsym(), t.lc)

    def getlabel(self):
        return self.root

    def mirror(t):
        if t.lc is None and t.rc is None:
            return True
        elif t.lc.lsym == t.rc.rsym:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def isSame(t):
        if t.lc is not None and t.rc is not None:
            if t.lc.getlabel != t.rc.getlabel :
                return False
            if t.lc.lc.isSame and t.rc.rc.isSame:
                return False
            if t.lc.rc.isSame and t.rc.lc.isSame:
                return False
        else:
            return False

l = Tree(1, Tree(2, 3, 4), Tree(2, 4, 3))
print(l.isSame())
```

Comment: We don't know what your code is supposed to do (we can only **guess** from the title), nor how it should behave on a specific example.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). And I agree with @mozway. Your current description reads like "here is a stone. what's wrong with it?" - well it's a stone, I don't know what it's supposed to look like, looks like a fine stone to me

Comment: the code is well written in the sense that there are no errors and you have declared the class and the methods correctly. The return result is `False`. What were you expecting or consider to be the correct answer?

Comment: Thanks for updating your question :) what are the other functions for if you only use "isSame"? Further, please explain your thoughts behind the code, because it's not obvious to me how you are trying to solve the task.

Answer (score 1):

Because so far, you gave us no goal to work against, I can only point out general programming mistakes:

```py
    def isSame(t):
        if t.lc is not None and t.rc is not None:
            if t.lc.getlabel != t.rc.getlabel :
                return False
            if t.lc.lc.isSame and t.rc.rc.isSame:
                return False
            if t.lc.rc.isSame and t.rc.lc.isSame:
                return False
        else:
            return False
```

- `t.lc.getlabel != t.rc.getlabel` should most likely be `t.lc.getlabel() != t.rc.getlabel()`, because it doesn't make sense to compare functions like this, I assume that you wanted to compare the label they return
- same for `isSame`

I **assume** that `isSame` is trying to find out whether the two child trees are identical. (note: this is somthing that belongs in the description of your question, this isn't an assumption I should have to make)

I further **assume** that this is the only function I should look at, because that's the only function you actually use. Again, something that should be in your description instead.

So then there are more problems:

- both of your `isSame` if statements are identical and don't do what you intend. `if t.lc.lc.isSame() and t.rc.rc.isSame()` is identical to `if t.lc.rc.isSame() and t.rc.lc.isSame()`, they are just flipped. Both check if the left child is symmetrical (which is probably not what you want) and then afterwards if the right child is symmetrical. You probably intended to compare whether the lift child is identical to the right child instead, which is not what this does. But again, something I have to assume, please specify what it should do in your question.

Further nitpicks:

- the `self` name is pretty much a standard in python, please don't use `t` instead. It's confusing. Use `self` consistently.
- `isSame` is a weird name for checking internal symmetry, it suggests that you are comparing it with another tree instead. I'd call it `isSymmetric` or similar.

I won't provide an actual "improved implementation" as I usually do, because I won't do that based on assumptions. Please add more specifity to your question.

Comment: i'm really sorry, thanks for your help! this is the exercise: Given the root of a binary tree, check whether it is a mirror of itself (i.e., symmetric around its center).